# Sqlite insert

Tags: android, sqlite

Доброго времени суток.
Не могу добавить данные в базу данных.
В наследнике SQLiteOpenHelper пишу следующие

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + GROUPS +
            " ( " + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1, " + GROUP_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            MIN + "integer, " + MAX + "integer );");

}
```

Добавление делаю так

```
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBHelper.GROUP_NAME, groupName);
        cv.put(DBHelper.MIN, min);
        cv.put(DBHelper.MAX, max);
        long i = db.insert(DBHelper.GROUPS, null, cv);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "" + i);
```

insert возвращает -1

Comment: Увы, не помогло ...

Comment: INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  DEFAULT 1

если ключ `AUTOINCREMENT`, то он явно уже не `NULL`. А так как он автоинкрементный, то `DEFAULT 1` не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, решил проблему, но не совсем доволен решением ибо магия (  - пересоздал наследника SQLiteOpenHelper, описал контракт  реализующий BaseColumns, по сути тот же код, но работает

Answer (score 0):

Вызывает сомнение правильность синтаксиса первичного ключа... Какой-то он у вас больно крутой. Я бы ограничился просто: `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Или же попробуйте использовать параметр `nullColumnHack` в `db.insert()`

Comment: @Barmaley расскажите пожалуйста как ?  в что на русском, что  английском все пояснения сводятся обычно к "в базе данных SQLite не разрешается вставлять полностью пустую строку, и если строка, полученная от клиента контент-провайдера, будет пустой, то только этому столбцу явно будет назначено значение null" 
Если я правильно понимаю, в тех случаях когда мы пытаемся вставить пустые значения, null вставляется только указному столбцу?
То есть в моем случае это выглядит так: db.insert(DBHelper.GROUPS, DBHelper.MAX, cv);
Это не помогло, но этот момент интересен и мало освещен

Comment: Нет, про `nullColumnHack` я ошибся - в вашем случае он точно не нужен. попробуйте просто задекларировать: INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`